# How to avoid routing an script file in cakephp root path

Tags: cakephp, routes

First of all, I want to apologize if this is repeated, I've look for the solution but maybe I dont know how to look for it.

I need to do a script which output is (more or less) +ticket-valido or -ticket-fallo so cakephp should ignore it. At this moment cakephp tells me that there is no controller.

But i don't know if this is possible, can anybody help me? I need at least to know what i should look for, is this about routing?.

Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: So you want an ajax response of just a line of text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you elaborate a little more, like what is the input? adn the output is just text line? it is in ajax? json? html?

Normally in cakephp you may NOT run a php script directly, you'll need at least a controller that calls for it. I think i see what you are trying to do.

First create a controller or use a controller that already exists, then create a function like  function runScript(). Now you need is a view that can be

```
<?php 

echo $result;

?>
```

being $result your +ticket-valido or -ticket-fallo

in the controller part you should put something like

```
function runScript(){
   //do some logic here to get the $result
   $this->set('result', $result);
   $this->layout = false;
}
```

this will return only the line, without anything else... hope this helps you

Comment: The output is just text, the problem is that the requisites of this are not defined by me, and i have to do it like this. I know that is not the best way. I think i can use layout = false!! Thank you very much. I'm going to try it :D